# Why does using __init__(self, **kwargs) return the following error code: SyntaxError: invalid syntax?

Tags: python, kivy

I try to run the code of my Kivy app, but things go wrong when I'm creating a new class. This is the code for it:

```
class MyGrid(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyGrid, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 2

        self.add_widget(Label(text="First Name: "))
        self.name = TextInput(multiline=False)
        self.add_widget(self.name)
```

The code doesn't work because of an error in the second line with def `__init__(self, **kwargs)`. The code returns:

```py
 SyntaxError: invalid syntax.
```

I don't know what's wrong with the syntax. What could be going wrong?

Comment: show complete error message

Comment: Your code looks ok. See if you didn't forgot a `:` or a parenthesis somewhere

Comment: @eyllanesc 
  File "app.py", line 12
    def__init__(self, **kwargs):
                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @Y.Ben: The code provided runs fine on Kivy versions 1.10.1 and 1.11.0.dev0. What is your OS and Kivy version?

Comment: @ikolim: I made a type somewhere in my code so now it's running just fine!

Answer (score 1):

For anyone coming from Tech with Tim's Video, being confused as to why this happens, there is a Typo beneath `Class MyGrid(GridLayout):`

There needs to be a space between `def` and `__init__`.